# Not able to change the position of a div in css with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Unable to change position.
It is still 250 px far from top.
Please, need help!

This is the jquery :

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
$('#menu').css('top',Math.max(0,250px-$(this).scrollTop()));
});
</script>
```

HTML ::

```
<div class='pure-u' id='menu' style='position: fixed;top:250px;'>
 <div class='pure-menu pure-menu-open'>
    <ul>

        <li class=' '>
            <a href='/base/'>Base</a>
        </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why use an outdated version of jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

`250px-$(this).scrollTop()` is the problem. `250px` is not a valid number to substract from. You should use this:

```
$('#menu').css('top',Math.max(0,(250-$(this).scrollTop()) + "px");
```

Comment: Then why just not use `.css("top", "0px")`?

Comment: thanks its working now!
please can you help me a bit more..
i want it to change again its position to its original postion when it comes back !

Comment: Save the initial position in a variable and add handler to `$(window).scroll(function() { <restore position via .css("top", <saved value>) })`